# How can I bulk edit exif data in Aperture Library?

Tags: aperture, macos

I run a tree farm.  I take pictures with my iPhone.

Exif data for the iphone includes Camera Make Apple  Camera Model iPhone X where X is the phone number.

Another program.  iPhoto I think created an Exif Image Description of AppleMark

Needless to say these give me grief when I search for Apple as in fruit tree.

The obvious workaround is to rename all my uses of Apple to AppleTree or some such.

Note, that I don't care to change it in the image, just the database.

Is there a search and replace editor that will work on an apple Aperture database?
I'd rather globally modify the camera maker to something else.